# A ThreadPool library in C++

Tags: c++, windows, threadpool

I am looking for a good and stable threadpool library for C++ that's fairly well documented.  I know about the Native Windows thread pool API and the newer Vista Thread Pool API, however my program requires some backward compatibility, so perhaps an outside library I can provide with the program is better.

I have looked into Boost's threadpool and it doesn't look bad at all, unfortunatly it is not very well documented.

Does anyone know any other libraries that have a ThreadPool in C++? (for Windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A portable threadpool library](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) that claims to be 'production ready'. You may want to  check that out.

Comment: @Tony there is a short tutorial at their site and the code comes with a few samples.

Answer (score 4):

[Intel TBB](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-tbb/) is another threading library that has some neat stuff. I find the framework for evaluating a tree of expressions in parallell especially nice.

Comment: please consider consolidating your answers.

Comment: @Vijay Really? I thought we preferred one item per answer to get meaningful discussions and to easily see what was accepted?

Answer (score 2):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) has a [threading library](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/threads.html) with some nice high-level operations like map/reduce etc, as well as low-level threading stuff and thread-pool support.

Qt might be a bit big for you though, but you can use a part of it pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ThreadPool](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.ThreadPool.html) and [TaskManager](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.TaskManager.html) classes from the [Poco C++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org/).

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the boost thread pool: this link might be useful: http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes

Answer (score 0):

There's also [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) which does thread-pooling over networks, so it's a fair bit more complex. (but deserves mentioning here, IMO)