# Creating a thread pool in one function call and using it from another function call

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, threadpool

I have a Fortran program that calls a C++ dll to do some mathematical operations on 10000 sets of data. The data sets are totally independent from each other. I was planning to create a thread pool and then send tasks to it. However, the call to the dll will be made more than 1000 times (each call the 10000 sets of data are being processed).

My question is: when I create the thread pool during the first call to the dll, what happens to this thread pool after the function in the dll returns ? Can the second call (and the remaining 998 calls) access the pool that was created during the first call.

Comment: Reading all those things here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686980(v=vs.85).aspx I dare say that if you spawn a few threads of your own and write your own logic you end up having fewer lines of code.  To keep the stuff around for the next call, you need some kind of singleton solution. The danger with all that is if your fortran code never calls a good Cleanup function for your DLL, you are a bit screwed.

Comment: @user2225104: *"To keep the stuff around for the next call, you need some kind of singleton solution."* - not true, as mentioned in my answer you can use a new thread or the heap to have data persist across calls - no singleton in sight.

Comment: How but "singleton" do you call your "having the stuff on the heap"? This is a singleton if you like it or not.

Comment: @user2225104: singletons are designs that ensure a program can only create one instance... with what I'm suggesting there could be any number of separate thread pools in different parts of the heap.  Nothing to do with singletons at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use the same thread pool, if you set things up right.

Objects created on the stack of the FORTRAN->C++ calling thread will be destroyed as that stack unwinds and control returns to FORTRAN, so it's not a good idea to have the thread pool management data on that stack.  You can, however:

- launch another thread that creates the thread pool management data/object, or
- allocate on the heap (using `new`) to decouple lifetime from the FORTRAN->C++ calls.

The latter is probably easier and cleaner... a pointer to the heap object/data managing the thread pool can be returned to FORTRAN and used as a "handle" for future calls, indicating the same thread pool should be used.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "launch another thread that creates the thread pool management data/object"

Comment: @Anas: if you're going to have a thread pool you'll need some object or data to manage it (for some libraries offering such an object, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853828/a-threadpool-library-in-c) or google yourself).  So, the text you're asking about suggests that you create a new thread from the FORTRAN/calling thread, then have that new thread create/own a thread pool object that; you'd then need some way for FORTRAN calls to pass new work to that thread-pool owning thread, e.g. perhaps `boost::lockfree:spsc_queue`.

Comment: I managed to implement the solution you suggested using the 'new' operator; However; what is the best way of synchronizing the C++ threads with FORTRAN. If the c++ function that is being called declares a semaphore variables, will these variables stay available after the function returns ?

Comment: @Anas: it really depends on the thread pool's interface... have you picked a thread pool library?  If you provide a link to the documentation, I'll take a look....  More generally, semaphores are pretty antiquated, and it's much more common to use a mutex (mutual exclusion variable) to serialise access to some code/data, sometimes paired with a condition variable (when one thread needs to wait a potentially long time for another thread - such as when the threads in the pool wait for new work to be provided from FORTRAN, or FORTRAN waits for processing to be complete).

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the fortran code, you can save yourself some sneaky hiding of your state you maintain by using 3 functions instead of one.

```
someStateHandle PrepareBackgroundWork();
// Then you do your actual call series...
DoMyMath(someStateHandle, args...);

// And when you are done with all that, you call
FinalizeBackgroundWork(someStateHandle);
```

If you do not have control over the fortran code, you will have to decide what you want to keep around (Threadpool stuff or thread handles and a few synchronization objects) and lazily initialize them.

```
struct MyWorkerContext
{
    size_t numberOfWorkerThreads;
    std::vector<HANDLE> workerHandles; 
    // ...
};
static MyWorkerContext* s_context = NULL; // Sorry - looks like a singleton to me.
void DoMyMath( args..)
{
    if(NULL == s_context) InitializeContext();
    if( NULL != s_context )
    {
         // do the calculations using all that infrastructure.
    }
}

E.g. in DLLMain() or hopefully earlier: clean up s_context.
```

Last not least, I think there is a "default thread pool", you might be able to use for that as well instead of creating your own.

Comment: I do have control over the Fortran code. So what you are suggesting is to write a function that creates the thread pool just before calling the DoMyMath function for the first time, and after done with all the calls I call another function that will destroy the thread pool. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes. This way to do it gives you some extra options (parameters in the initializer function). And it gives you a foolproof scheme for cleaning up.

Comment: Just to clarify,      someStateHandle PrepareBackgroundWork();  mentioned in you answer is a call to a c++ function inside the dll to create the thread pool. right ? are you sure when that function returns to Fortran the pool will continue to exist ?

Comment: PrepareBackgroundWork() is declared and defined by the DLL and called from fortran. The "someStateHandle" can be simply a more or less camouflaged pointer to your heap object you keep the state in.